# Show popup with item info on clicking add to cart

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to display a popup with item name and its other attributes like color, manufacturer, etc when we add this product in cart. 
I need to display the popup on clicking add to cart button on product page.
Please guide me, I have tried few things like getting product info after "product_add_to_cart_complete" event but didn't get appropriate result. 
I want to show all the product info as it is coming in cart page, like if we have a configurable product, then product is appearing with its option on cart page, same is wanted on popup also.

Comment: See if these guys can amend their extension to meet this requirement - http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/popup-splash-screen.html

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps for creating popup window, you will need to create your block for displaying the attributes.

add include below files using layout xml

```
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/window.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
<action method="addCss"><name>lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css</name></action>
```

below is the prototype function which will invoke the widowbox

```
function showPopup(sUrl) {
    oPopup = new Window({
    id:'popup_window',
    className: 'magento',
    url: sUrl,
    width: 820,
    height: 600,
    minimizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    showEffectOptions: {
        duration: 0.4
    },
    hideEffectOptions:{
        duration: 0.4
    },
    destroyOnClose: true
    });
    oPopup.setZIndex(100);
    oPopup.showCenter(true);
}

function closePopup() {
    Windows.close('popup_window');
}
```

invoke function using below code

```
$('test_me').observe('click', function(event) {
    showPopup('<?php echo Mage::getUrl("here_url_of_block_which_will_have_those_attributes") ?>');
    //Event.stop(oEvent);
});
```

Comment: I have the popup, but problem is in getting the content.

Comment: showPopup('Url_for_loading_content');

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't make myself clear. By content I mean I am facing problem in retrieving the item content from Magento. Means I am not getting proper code to get all the item properties as in cart page to show on popup.